# Yii2 AppAsset not generating css/js links in the layout

Tags: layout, assets, yii2

Well, I declared all my CSS and JavaScript stuff in AppAsset but I can't make it to display the css and js links in the  in the front-end view. Here are my files:

app/assets/AppAsset.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'assets/plugins/weather-icon/css/weather-icons.min.css',
        ...
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

and here is my layout (app/modules/admin/layouts/admin.php):

```
<?php

use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php $this->head() ?>
        <?= $this->render('partials/head') ?>
    </head>
<body class="tooltips">
    <?= $this->render('partials/colour_panel') ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?= $this->render('partials/top_navbar') ?>
            <?= $this->render('partials/left_sidebar') ?>
            <?= $this->render('partials/right_sidebar') ?>
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <?= $content ?>
                    <?= $this->render('partials/footer') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $this->render('partials/scripts') ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

I had same issue. In my case layout has no `<?php $this->beginBody() ?>` and 
 `<?php $this->endBody() ?>` sections inside `<body></body>` tags.

It should be like this:

```
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
   <!--content-->
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
```

Hope it helps somebody

Comment: OK so this worked but why? these statements are not in my 'main' layout (where the JS works) but when I use a 'blank' (custom) layout the JS doesn't load without beginBody() and endBody() statements?

Comment: @gvanto Ussualy JS tags are placed before closing </body> tag (or inside <head></head>). I think  ```$this->endBody()``` statements tells Yii where the end of the HTML body is. Without it Yii doesn't know where <body> ends and cannot plase <script> tags before it.

Comment: The same behavior arises if     `<?php $this->endPage() ?>` is missing at the end

Answer (score 7):

This part

```
<?php $this->head() ?>
```

should copy them in the head automatically. Are you sure the paths that you use are correct?

```
public $sourcePath = '@vendor';
public $css = [
    'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
```

means that your files are found in the vendor/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css are you sure that is right? as that looks wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure the path to the files is okay. At present, the directory which consists all my css and js files is vendor/scripts. All the files from vendor are copied in "web/assets/2b2e6bcf" but unfortunately it seems that none of them appears in the head section of the layout. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't be pretty sure, be sure. in your project navigate to the main folder of your application then go to vendor/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css and confirm that there is a file there. No decent yii2 instalation should have anything there.

Comment: I have already checked numerous times. The files were there but were not declared in the head of the html layout. Now I decided to put them in the "web/assets" directory and again it doesn't seem to  work. Check the main post.

Comment: try removing all the ->render( and use ->renderPartial( or to make a test just remove every partial views just to make sure everything is ok in the views.

Comment: I removed them all, also tried <?= $this->head() ?> instead of <?php $this->head() ?> but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your asset folder file size bigger than 20MB. I think asset manager not created big folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I mistakenly removed below line from `frontend/views/layouts/main.php`

```
<?php $this->head() ?>
```

CSS starts working when above line added.